Update object inside array inside another JSON object
I have a huge JSON object with an array of objects inside it. I have to add key:value pair to a specific object in the array. For example, let the input object is:
{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "value": 1,
        "param": {
          "p1": "par1"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "value": 2,
        "param": {
          "p1": "par2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "value": 3,
        "param": {
          "p1": "par3"
        }
      }
    ],
    "c": 4,
    "d": 5
  }
}

Using index the modification is easy:
 jq '.a.b[0].param += {new: "QQQ"}'

But I can not be 100% sure of index. I have to specify the object with the name tag .name == "name1".
How to modify an object identified by name tag?

This may not be the best way, but it works:
.a.b |= map(if .name == "name1" then .param.new = "QQQ" else . end)


The |= is the trick I missed! Exact expression is jq '.a.b |= map(if .name == "name1" then (.param += {new: "QQQ"}) else . end)'. Thanks.

It feels natural, at least to me, to use select() to do the selection of the element to update, and then to use map() to map the selection and assignment to all elements of the b sub-array:
jq '.a.b |= map(select(.name == "name1").param += { new: "QQQ" })'  file

or, shorter
jq '.a.b |= map(select(.name == "name1").param.new = "QQQ")' file

Or, you could pick out all the param entries from the elements of the b array and update them.  This would be closer to your own command that updates the first element of b unconditionally:
jq '(.a.b[] | select(.name == "name1").param) += { new: "QQQ" }'

or, shorter,
jq '(.a.b[] | select(.name == "name1").param).new = "QQQ"'  file


The second is the one I prefer +1
